# Can not use the v2x and wifi dongle on RB5 because of the rndis is not existing

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, usb, rndis

I want to use V2X on RB5 and i follow this website tutorial.
https://unex.com.tw/en/faq-en/som/quickly-som-v2x-som-properly-integrated-linux-host-platform/
Then I find my RB5 doesnt have RNDIS module.

```
sh-4.4# depmod rndis_host.ko
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed rndis_host.ko
sh-4.4# modprobe rndis_host.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module rndis_host.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.95
```

Moreover, i go to this file direction`drivers/net/usb/Kconfig:234 │`, there dont have usb/Kconfig file

```
sh-4.4# pwd
/lib/modules/4.19.95/kernel/drivers/net
sh-4.4# ls *
ath
```

Is any can help me sovlve the problems. Should i reinstall linux system or kernel ? and how to do?

Comment: As the tutorial mentions it also, make sure that the kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_USB_NET_RNDIS_HOST`. If its value is set to `y`, then there won't be a module generated, but the driver will be built into the kernel, and it should be ready to use without further steps. If its value is set to `m`, then the corresponding module should be generate.

Comment: Do you know where is the location of the Kconfig in RB5， I use the my Ubuntu PC file direction, but i cannot find it.

Comment: Sorry, but have no idea what `RB5` or `V2X` are.